# JQuery Change color base on table value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a count column and a target column

I want to write an if statement:
If count is less than 10 percent over the target   (make the cell yellow)
If the count is more than 10 percent over the target (make cell red)
If count is < Target (make the cell green)
If the count is = target (make cell green)

Below is my html. Thanks

```
<table id="ytdTable" border="1" style="width:100%">
   <tr class="trHeader trHeaderMain">
       <th colspan="3">Table1</th></tr>
            <tr class="trHeader trHeaderSub"></tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Count</th>
                <th>Target</th>
    <tr><td>Name1</td> 
        <td>5</td>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Name2</td> 
        <td>100</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Name3</td> 
        <td>35</td>
        <td>35</td>
    </tr>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Please would you also show us your approach? For example the javascript you've got so far and error messages if any. Your question is very broad and it helps others to help you if you can be more specific. Also check out this question for general guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And of course: Welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#ytdTable tr:gt(2)').each(function () {
    var $cells = $(this).find('td'),
        val = +$cells.eq(1).text(),
        target = +$cells.eq(2).text(),
        ratio = val / target,
        color = 'green';
    if (ratio >= 1) {
        color = ratio > 1.1 ? 'red' : 'yellow';
    }
    $cells.eq(1).css('background', color)

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p8d9fhct/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2c48jpb1/5/ .  I recommend adding classes to the cells like in the fiddle then adding this jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.item').each(function(){
    var countNum = $(this).find('.count').text();
    var targetNum = $(this).find('.target').text();
    var percent = (countNum / targetNum) * 100;
    var diff = percent - 100;

    if(diff <= 0){
        $(this).css('background','green');   
    }else if (diff > 10){
        $(this).css('background','red');
    }else if (diff < 10 && diff > 1){
         $(this).css('background','yellow');
    }

});

});
```

Comment: @charlietfl's is a much cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/8L7v0pbp/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ytdTable td.count").each(function() {
        var countValue = parseInt($(this).html());
        var targetValue = parseInt($(this).siblings(".target").html());

        if(countValue > targetValue) {
            if(((countValue-targetValue)/targetValue)*100 < 10) {
                $(this).css("background", "yellow");                 
            } else {
                $(this).css("background", "red");
            }
        } else {
            $(this).css("background", "green"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: should always use radix argument with parseInt() or can run into unexpected results especially if any leading zeros exist